# JavaScript: understanding scope chain

Tags: javascript, javascript-scope

What is the scope chain in following code snippet -

```js
var name = 'John';

function foo() {
  if (false) {
    var name = 'James';
  }
  console.log(name);
}

foo();
```

I got couple of queries regarding this -

- Why the logger in function `foo` is printing `undefined` even when the variable
  is available in global scope?  Is it due to the fact that same variable
  is re-declared in conditional falsy block and so the global variable is
  getting removed from the scope?
- Also if we replace the variable declaration under if statement inside function `foo` from `var` to `let`, the logger inside the function `foo` prints name from global scope. How this is working?

Comment: Your function re-declares a local `name` variable. Declarations with `var` are treated as if they appear at the very top of the enclosing function.

Comment: Just forget about `var`, use `let` !

Comment: Under the term "js hoisting" you will find a lot of good explanations of this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is because the variables declared with `var` have function scope and they are hoisted to the top of the `function`. It logs `undefined` due to hoisting.

Variables declared with `let` have block scope so until the `if` block is not executed the variable `name` is not declared.

Even if you change it with `if(true)` it will not work because the variable will only be available inside the block. `{}` not outside.

Here is the example how `let` works.

```js
if(true){
  let x = 3
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Got it, had an idea about hoisting before, but didn't knew that variables are hoisted even if they are declared in falsy if block.

Answer (score 0):

If you redeclare variable with `var`, it has the scope in the whole function. If you do it with `let` instead of `var`, it will be available only in the `if` scope.

```
var name = 'John';

function foo() {
  if (false) {
    let name = 'James';
  }
  console.log(name);
}

foo();
```